# Doxygen-how to document files with non-standard extension (.INI)

Tags: doxygen

I have a simple question: how do I document .INI file?

I have a C++ project with the following layout:

```
readme.txt
src
    main.cpp
data
    simple.ini
```

I have no problem generating document from readme.txt and main.cpp, but the document in simple.ini does not show in the html output at all. I have fixed the Doxygen file to include the following:

```
INPUT = . src data
FILE_PATTERNS = *.cpp *.txt *.ini
```

That did not help. I also explicitly specify simple.ini:

```
INPUT = readme.txt data/simple.ini src
```

But it did not work either. Within simple.ini, I use ';' for comment:

```
; @file simple.ini
; This file will do blah blah blah
[section1]
key1 = foo
key2 = bar
...
```

I also tried to use '#' for comment char, but it did not work, either. How do I make doxygen to process simple.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doxygen expects `/**` or  `///` for starting a doxygen-aware comment block. I don't know if it works, but I would try to comment with:

```
; /// @file simple.ini
; /// This file will do blah blah blah
...
```

Comment: Thank you mouviciel, it works. However, the output for text between the @code and @endcode block is messy: it includes ";" because Doxygen did not recognize ";" as a comment char. For now, I use a .TXT file with the same name to document my .INI file.

Answer (score 4):

To add custom file extensions to doxygen you must edit two things in the config file:

- FILE_PATTERNS to include the extension often `*.extension \`
- EXTENSION_MAPPING to be `.extension=parser` where parser is C, C#, C++, Python etc.

In your case set '.extension' as '.ini' and 'parser' as C.
Doxygen expects two lines of either the following `///` or `//!`. It also accepts multi-line `/**` and `/*!`.
OR
set 'parser' to 'Python' to use `##` style comments as # is accepted by .ini as a comment although not recommended. This should remove your need for ;s

Answer (score -1):

I would say Doxygen lacks the feature of documenting

- build scripts
- configuration files
- custom scripts for use in your own vm

So the ultimate solution is to fork Doxygen, and add ability to process arbitrary language, like Notepad++ or Kate. On the way, you should also clean up its messy 2002-style HTML output, so it no longer generates a div soup.