# Is there an equivalent to the javadoc command for ini files?

Tags: documentation, ini

I have a long ini file, splitted into section. In each section, there are a bunch of parameters, most of them being optionnal.

What I want is a way to extract, either from the ini file or from the code used to parse it, a list of parameters, their possible values, their usage, and the expected data type.

Does it exist, such a tool?

Comment: Do you have Doxygen ? You can document your ini with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216285/doxygen-how-to-document-files-with-non-standard-extension-ini however it a pain.

Comment: Interestin possibility. Thank you. however I think I'll go a different way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find any tool for that, i decided to create mine.

So, you can follow [this link to a tool](https://gist.github.com/843613) that will hapily consume your .ini file. It's a groovy script (requiring as a consequence the Groovy interpreter on your machine) that is quite self documented.

Documentation format is as follows :

```
## @brief Description
## @type data type
## @mandatory
## @optionnal
## @deprecated
## @default
FieldName = value
```

Notice for now it's targetted at producing french output.